# How to get IP and PORT of a service published by AVAHI in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, bonjour, avahi, nsnetservicebrowser

I am using NSNetServiceBrowser and is able to find service list published by AVAHI in "didFindService" which looks like :
Service appeared:  local. _https._tcp. TEMP-Mobileyes5-1C497B9ED382 -1
Service appeared:  local. _https._tcp. TEMP-Mobileyes5-1C497B8E3916 -1
Service appeared:  local. _https._tcp. TEMP-Mobileyes5-1C497B9ED380 -1

But not able to find IP Address and Port number of same service. I have found that code is not reaching in "netServiceDidResolveAddress" My Code is :

```
class ServiceDiscovery : NSObject, NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate,NSNetServiceDelegate {

    var _browser:NSNetServiceBrowser!
    var _service: NSNetService!
    var services = [NSNetService]()
    override init() {
        _browser = NSNetServiceBrowser()
        super.init()
        _browser.delegate = self
        _browser.includesPeerToPeer = true
        _browser.searchForServicesOfType("_https._tcp.", inDomain: "local.")
        _browser.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

    }


    func netServiceBrowser(browser: NSNetServiceBrowser, didFindDomain domainString: String, moreComing: Bool) {
        print(domainString)
    }

    func netServiceBrowser(aNetServiceBrowser: NSNetServiceBrowser, didFindService aNetService: NSNetService, moreComing: Bool) {
       print("Service appeared: \(aNetService)")
        services.append(aNetService)
        aNetService.delegate = self
        aNetService.resolveWithTimeout(5.0)
    }


    func netServiceBrowser(browser: NSNetServiceBrowser, didNotSearch errorDict: [String : NSNumber]) {
        print(errorDict)
    }

    func netServiceBrowser(browser: NSNetServiceBrowser, didRemoveService service: NSNetService, moreComing: Bool) {
        print("Service removed: \(service)")

    }

    func netService(sender: NSNetService, didNotResolve errorDict: [String : NSNumber]) {
        print(errorDict)
    }

    func netServiceDidResolveAddress(sender: NSNetService) {
        print(sender.addresses![0])
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

The possible reason for your problem could be that you are calling the

```
aNetService.resolveWithTimeout(5.0)
```

inside another function, so as soon as

```
didFindService
```

finishes, the local variable **aNetService** gets destroyed (as it is a local variable for didFindService function)

**SOLUTION**

I see that you've already defined a variable at the top with class-wide scope named **"_service"**
Hence, use that by using

```
_service = aNetService
_service.resolveWithTimeout(5.0)
```

inside your **didFindService**
this should solve your problem. And, *netServiceDidResolveAddress* should get called now.

Comment: Thank you for the good solution Aishwary, but unfortunately i was not getting the correct address with your solution so i did some changes in my code and now it is working.

Comment: still problem is didFind method not get called every time in iPhone's but in iPad and simulators it get called each and every time. i dont know why

Comment: `func netServiceBrowser(_ browser: NetServiceBrowser, didRemove     service: NetService, moreComing: Bool){
        print("didRemoveService")
        if let ix = self.services.index(of: service) {
            self.services.remove(at: ix)
            print("removing a service")
            if !moreComing {
                self.updateInterface()
            }
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation
class ServiceDiscovery : NSObject, NetServiceBrowserDelegate,NetServiceDelegate {

    var _browser:NetServiceBrowser!
    var _service: NetService!
    var services = [NetService]()


    func searchServices(){
        self.services.removeAll()
        _browser = NetServiceBrowser()
        _browser.delegate = self
        _browser.includesPeerToPeer = true
        _browser.searchForServices(ofType: "_https._tcp.", inDomain: "local.")
        _browser.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
    }


    func updateInterface () {
        for service in self.services {
            if service.port == -1 {
                print("service \(service.name) of type \(service.type)" +
                    " not yet resolved")
                service.delegate = self
                service.resolve(withTimeout: 0.0)
            } else {

                let deviceLanController = DeviceLanController()
                let dict = NetService.dictionary(fromTXTRecord: service.txtRecordData()!)
                let id = self.copyStringFromTXTDict(dict as [AnyHashable: Any]?, which: "id")
                var ipAdd = ""
                if let address = service.addresses{
                if let addressOfFirstDevice = address.first{
                    let theAddress = addressOfFirstDevice as Data
                    var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
                    if getnameinfo((theAddress as NSData).bytes.bindMemory(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: theAddress.count), socklen_t(theAddress.count),
                                   &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count), nil, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0 {
                        if let numAddress = String(validatingUTF8: hostname) {
                            ipAdd = numAddress
                        }
                    }

                    if let serviceId = id{
                        deviceLanController.setDeviceAvailable(serviceId, host: ipAdd, port: "\(service.port)")
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    fileprivate func copyStringFromTXTDict(_ dict: [AnyHashable: Any]?, which: String) -> String? {
        // Helper for getting information from the TXT data
        var resultString: String? = nil
        if let data = dict?[which as NSObject] as! Data? {
            resultString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!

        }
        return resultString
    }



    func netServiceBrowser(_ browser: NetServiceBrowser, didFindDomain domainString: String, moreComing: Bool) {
        print("didFindDomain")
        print(domainString)
    }

    func netServiceBrowser(_ aNetServiceBrowser: NetServiceBrowser, didFind aNetService: NetService, moreComing: Bool) {
        print("didFindService")
        self.services.append(aNetService)
        if !moreComing {
            aNetService.stop()
            self.updateInterface()
        }
    }

    func netServiceBrowser(_ browser: NetServiceBrowser, didRemove service: NetService, moreComing: Bool){
        print("didRemoveService")
        if let ix = self.services.index(of: service) {
            self.services.remove(at: ix)
            print("removing a service")
            if !moreComing {
                self.updateInterface()
            }
        }
    }

    func netServiceBrowser(_ browser: NetServiceBrowser, didNotSearch errorDict: [String : NSNumber]) {
        print("didNotSearch")
        print(errorDict)
    }



    func netService(_ sender: NetService, didNotResolve errorDict: [String : NSNumber]) {
        print("didNotResolve",sender)
        print(errorDict)

    }

    func netServiceWillResolve(_ sender: NetService) {
        print("netServiceWillResolve",sender)
    }
    func netServiceDidResolveAddress(_ sender: NetService) {
        print("netServiceDidResolveAddress",sender)
       self.updateInterface()
    }

}
```

This answer solved my problem. I am resolving and saving each address in my coredata so i can use that address for connecting local services.